# How to initiate windows logoff in Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

Long time ago I made a small taskbar application that was able to shutdown the computer or logoff the current user.
Unfortunatelly I've lost the source code (anyway it was written in Visual C if I remember well).
I admit I'm too lazy to search deeply on the net to find a solution.

Please help me with some code how to solve this problem. As I finish the app I'd like to develop using this code I'll share it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the working code here: https://github.com/tbikfalvi/ChildController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ExitWindowsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868(v=vs.85).aspx) API to log out of the current session.

```
#include <windows.h>

ExitWindowsEx(EWX_LOGOFF, 0);
```

Comment: This example also works, but the other came first. Thanks for help.

Comment: This works, too bad the Shutdown parameter does not have effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the following command from your Qt application: `shutdown /l`. For example:

```
QProcess proc;
proc.start("shutdown", QStringList() << "/l");
if (!proc.waitForStarted()) {
    return 1;
}
```

Additional `/f` option will force the logging off.

Comment: Thanks, going to check this (thumb up)

Comment: I don't get it, but calling from the app it does't do anything. Calling it from command line is ok.